# Как правильно сравнить данные из двух CSV файлов? Отрисовка точек попадающих между графиками

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Смысл в чём - есть два .csv файла с данными, один на 600 строк, второй на ~2500. В каждом одинаковые значения столбцов. Столбцов 6, нужны какие-то два из них, для примера возьмём `time` и `r`.

В Matplotlib по данным из первого файла отрисовывается какой-то график. Потом, по этим двум полям отрисовываются две границы (значение поля `time` и значение `r` +- 200, как вариант). Дальше, из второго файла мне нужно отрисовать точки (`scatter`) по этим же полям, но так, чтобы при попадании в вычисленные границы (или проще говоря между графиками 1 и 2) они отрисовывались одним цветом, а при вылезании за границы, цвет был другой.

Как правильно сравнивать точку из одного файла, с точкой из другого?

Я пробовала организовать это через `if...else`, но поскольку массивы разного размера, вылезает ошибка:

> ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare.

Ошибочный код такой:

```py
if (mixed_r > threshold_down_0_r) and (mixed_r < threshold_up_0_r):
    ax1.scatter(mixed_time, mixed_r, marker='x', color='b')
else:
    ax1.scatter(mixed_time, mixed_r, marker='x', color='y')
```

Значения берутся с помощью pandas:

```py
mixed = pd.read_csv("mixed.csv")
mixed_time = mixed['time']
mixed_r = mixed['r']
```

Мне нужно, чтобы те точки, которые попадают в "границы" одного из графиков, окрашивались в его цвет. Сейчас все точки отрисованы синим.

Код построения графика, примерно, такой:

```py
# данные траекторий
trajectory0 = pd.read_csv("trajectory0.csv")
trajectory0_time = trajectory0['time']
trajectory0_r = trajectory0['r']
ax1.plot(trajectory0_time, trajectory0_r, ".")

threshold_down_0_r = trajectory0['r'] - r_threshold/2
threshold_up_0_r = trajectory0['r'] + r_threshold/2

ax1.plot(trajectory0_time, threshold_down_0_r, c='b')
ax1.plot(trajectory0_time, threshold_up_0_r, c='b')

ax1.fill_between(trajectory0_time, threshold_up_0_r, threshold_down_0_r, alpha=0.2, color='b')

# дальше отрисовка точек-замеров (именно этот момент, я не знаю как правильно организовать)
ax1.scatter(mixed_time, mixed_r, marker='x')
```

Код для остальных графиков аналогичен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не следует отрисовывать график в цикле - scatter воспринимает iterable, поэтому сначала рисуете основной график, а потом второй график разбиваете на три (ниже, между и выше соответствующих границ) и рисуете их каждый отдельно. Можете привести воспроизводимый код с данными, чтобы получить более конкретный ответ.

Comment: можете выложить CSV файлы на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Тот, который длинный, надо прочитать и *скомпрессировать* по какому-либо из столбцов. Т.е. берём, например, `time ± delta`, если точка попадает, заносим её в список, то есть получаем список списков в итоге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я советую вам использовать возможности `pandas`. как именно вы будете разделять данные - дело ваше, я попытаюсь показать принцип. Раз исходных данных нет, то сделаем на примерных сетах

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x**2 for x in range(10)]) # примерный датафрейм с основным графиком

df1['threshold_up'] = df1[0] + 10 # вычисляем пороги и заносим эти значения в тот же df
df1['threshold_down'] = df1[0] - 10

# рисуем основной график и пороги
plt.plot(df1[0])
plt.fill_between(df1.index, df1['threshold_down'] ,df1['threshold_up'], alpha=0.2, color='b')
```

Получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
# создаем второй датафрейм с данными для точек
np.random.seed(12)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(81, 10), index=df1.index, columns=['mixed'])

# принимая во внимание, что основной и доп. график разделяют общую ось абсцисс
# объединяем
df1 = df1.join(df2)
```

получается такой датафрейм:

```
    0  threshold_up  threshold_down  mixed
0   0            10             -10     75
1   1            11              -9     27
2   4            14              -6      6
3   9            19              -1      2
4  16            26               6      3
5  25            35              15     67
6  36            46              26     76
7  49            59              39     48
8  64            74              54     22
9  81            91              71     49
```

Далее, делим его на части, которые попадают в границы порогов и которые не попадают:

```
special_dots = df1[(df1['threshold_down'].le(df1['mixed'])) & (df1['threshold_up'].ge(df1['mixed']))]
common_dots = pd.concat([df1, special_dots, special_dots]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

# и отрисовываем:
plt.scatter(common_dots.index, common_dots['mixed'], color='g', marker='x')
plt.scatter(special_dots.index, special_dots['mixed'], color='b', marker='x')

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]